# Migration from WebSphere to WebLogic

Tags: java, spring, migration, icefaces

I have an webapplication running on WebSphere using JDK 1.6, Spring 2.5.6 and iceFaces 1.8.2. I need to migrate that webapp to WebLogic. So I updated JDK to 1.8 and Spring to 4.2. The iceFaces framework I dont change because of the number of change on my source code.
When I deploy the application I got the following:

```
com.sun.faces.config.ConfigurationException: Factory 'javax.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactory' was not configured properly.
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:330)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.process(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:236)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigManager.initialize(ConfigManager.java:439)
        at com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener.contextInitialized(ConfigureListener.java:227)
        at weblogic.servlet.internal.EventsManager$FireContextListenerAction.run(EventsManager.java:705)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: javax.faces.FacesException: com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplGivenPreviousImpl(FactoryFinderInstance.java:409)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getImplementationInstance(FactoryFinderInstance.java:253)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinderInstance.getFactory(FactoryFinderInstance.java:549)
        at javax.faces.FactoryFinder.getFactory(FactoryFinder.java:283)
        at com.sun.faces.config.processor.FactoryConfigProcessor.verifyFactoriesExist(FactoryConfigProcessor.java:328)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
Caused By: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
        at javax.faces.application.Application.subscribeToEvent(Application.java:1797)
        at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.ClientWindowFactoryImpl.<init>(ClientWindowFactoryImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        Truncated. see log file for complete stacktrace
```

Are there some way to resolve that or I need to change my iceFaces version?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think i resolved that including jsf 1.2 libs on my war file.

Still getting another errors, soon I update the answer if it worked or not.

**UPDATE:**

Yes, this solved my problem... Now webapplication is deployed sucessful. (Still getting httpError 500 when open my login page...)